# Where can I find the .tff files for the default font-families Chrome uses?

Tags: html, css

Where can I find the .tff files for the default font-families Chrome uses. For example, ‘serif’.

Comment: The font used is OS-specific, as is their location and format.

Comment: It's in the customize font setting, but why do you need it? Remember users can (and will) have different font set depending on their OS

Comment: I really just wanted to know as I'm learning about the height letters take up (ascender, descender all that stuff). @Martheen if users have different font depending on their OS isn't that a further complication? For example if I set font-family as `serif` it's not going to be the same for all computers? But if I did a google font it would?

Comment: "it's not going to be the same for all computers", yes and that's usually what they want. You can get fancy with google font but I'd really hate for someone pushing additional resources just to have the letter having exact size etc. A webpage is supposed to be responsive, if it can handle different screen sizes, it sure can handle different fonts.

Comment: 'It's in the customize font setting' - could you be a bit more specific? Is one of the reasons ems is used as a unit so much to try and make websites 'font-responsive'?

Comment: If there are two or more commenters, always use @ to mention since there will be no notification otherwise. On Chrome setting, just type "customize font" on the search box. Yes, in general use em because even if they're using the exact same font, the window size can vary

Comment: @Martheen Thanks, I'm trying to find the literal .tff file so I can upload it to this website (https://fontdrop.info/)